# How do I avoid permissions problems when syncing files between several Linux systems?

Tags: linux, permissions, dropbox

I have been using dropbox to sync between 8 different Linux machines. I use BasKet notepads to keep track of projects and it as well as many other applications seem to have problems syncing due to permissions, claiming 'can't sync "such and such file": permission denied.' There are plenty of guides on how to fix this temporarily, involving using the hidden "fix permissions" button in the interface, or using chmod, but the problem comes back because of the umask creating permissions that can't be synced between systems.

What is the best practice for solving this issue? Is there another system such as perhaps Isync with Google Drive, OwnCloud, or Ubuntu One that would be better than Dropbox in this case? Do I just need to host my Dropbox on a FAT partition? Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: is drop-box installed as root on the Linux machine ?

Comment: Possibly? Come to think of it I used Kfilebox on one machine (Chakra Project) which downloads and installs the dropbox client I believe as a user. On many of the other systems I just installed the Ubuntu package. Should I ensure it is installed as root? Would that help the problem?

Comment: make sure its installed with root permissions

Comment: So a quick way to check that would be to ensure that dropbox is installed under /usr and not under just the user I assume?

Comment: second thinking installing dropbox as root is not the best practice in the world :)
try this 
chmod 755 ~/Dropbox or wherever its installed

Comment: Done that, it fixes the problem only temporarily it seems and then goes back causing problems after the files are recreated. Very weird, I've even tried applying it recursively to all sub dirs.

Comment: try to add the user to the sudo list with permision to the dropbox folder

Comment: May have solved the problem. I noticed the problem seemed to be on the systems I was dual-booting windows and linux and the dropbox folder being shared on an ntfs partition. I setup dropbox in my home folder on one system and it succeeded in syncing all the files so that may solve the problem on all the others. Thanks for the tips.